# Compiler choosing the wrong initializer

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2 ...)` error that keeps popping up that I need some help with. I believe I've managed to pin down the source of the malformed pointer, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Apparently the swift compiler is choosing the wrong initializer for one of my classes. According to Instruments, sometimes when the class `Description` is initialized, it calls the initializer for `LyricBlock`. Not all the time, just sometimes. It does this regardless of whether the compiler is set to -Onone or -O whole-module-optimization.

Here's what the two classes look like:

```
class LyricBlock: Node, LeftDelimited, RightDelimited {

    var leftDelimiter: Delimiter

    var rigthDelimiter: Delimiter

    init(start: Int, body: Range<Int>, end: Int) {
        self.leftDelimiter = Delimiter(range: start..<body.lowerBound)
        self.rightDelimiter = Delimiter(range: body.upperBound..<end)
        super.init(range: body)
    }

}

class Description: Node, LeftDelimited, RightDelimited {

    var leftDelimiter: Delimiter

    var leftDelimiter: Delimiter

    init(start: Int, body: Range<Int>, end: Int) {
        self.leftDelimiter = Delimiter(range: start..<body.lowerBound)
        self.rightDelimiter = Delimiter(range: body.upperBound..<end)
        super.init(range: body)
    }

}
```

As you can see, `LyricBlock` and `Description` inherit from a `Node` base class and share a couple protocols in common, but otherwise they have nothing to do with each other.

Some possibly relevant code:

```
class Node {

    weak var parent: Node?

    var next: Node?

    var firstChild: Node?

    weak var lastChild: Node?

    let offset: Int

    internal(set) var length: Int

    init(range: Range<Int>) {
        self.offset = range.lowerBound
        self.length = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound
    }

    func addChild(_ child: Node) {
        if firstChild == nil {
            firstChild = child
        } else {
            lastChild?.next = child
        }

        lastChild = child
        child.parent = self
    }

}

class Parser {

    // ...

    func processLine(in buffer: Buffer) {
        // Parse the current line as a block node.
        var block = blockForLine(in: buffer)

        // Try to find an appropriate container node. If none can be found, block will be replaced with Description.
        let container = appropriateContainer(for: &block, in: buffer)
        container.addChild(block)

        // Edge case to parse first-line lyrics
        if let cueBlock = block as? CueBlock {
            if let lyricBlock = scanForLyric(in: buffer, at: cueBlock.direction.range.lowerBound) {
                let lyricContainer = LyricContainer(range: lyricBlock.range.lowerBound..<endOfLineCharNumber)
                lyricContainer.addChild(lyricBlock)

                cueBlock.replaceDirection(with: lyricContainer)

                parseInlines(for: lyricBlock, in: buffer)
            }
        }

        // Parse inlines as appropriate
        switch block {
        case is FacsimileBlock, is Description, is LyricBlock:
            parseInlines(for: block, in: buffer)
        // ...
        }
    }

    func blockForLine(in buffer: Buffer) -> Node {
        let whitespace = buffer.scanForFirstNonspace(at: charNumber, limit: endOfLineCharNumber)

        // ... 

        let endWhitespace = buffer.scanBackwardForFirstNonspace(at: endOfLineCharNumber, limit: wc)

        let description = Description(start: charNumber, body: whitespace..< endWhitespace, end: endOfLineCharNumber)
        return description
    }

    func appropriateContainer(for block: inout Node, in buffer: Buffer) -> Node {
        switch block {
        // These block types can only ever be level-1
        case is Header, is Description, is EndBlock, is HorizontalBreak:
            return root

        // ...

        case is LyricBlock:
            guard let cueContainer = root.lastChild as? CueContainer else { break }

            guard let cueBlock = cueContainer.lastChild as? CueBlock else { break }

            guard let direction = cueBlock.direction as? LyricContainer else { break }

            direction.extendLengthToInclude(node: block)
            cueBlock.extendLengthToInclude(node: direction)
            cueContainer.extendLengthToInclude(node: cueBlock)
            return direction

        default:
            break
        }

        let whitespace = buffer.scanForFirstNonspace(at: charNumber, limit: endOfLineCharNumber)
        let endWhitespace = buffer.scanBackwardForFirstNonspace(at: endOfLineCharNumber, limit: wc)

        // Invalid syntax, time to fail gracefully
        block = Description(start: charNumber, body: whitespace..< endWhitespace, end: endOfLineCharNumber)
        return root
    }

    func parseInlines(for stream: Node, in buffer: Buffer) {
        // ... scans buffer for inlines and enques them in queue

        while let next = queue.dequeue() {
            let nextRange = next.rangeIncludingMarkers

            if nextRange.lowerBound > j {
                let lit = Literal(range: j..<nextRange.lowerBound)
                stream.addChild(lit)
            }

            stream.addChild(next)

            j = nextRange.upperBound
        }

        if j < endOfLineCharNumber {
            let lit = Literal(range: j..<nodeRange.upperBound)
            stream.addChild(lit)
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

As a side note, I wondered if I might be running into a mangling issue with the class signatures and  tried making `rightDelimiter` and `leftDelimiter` properties of `Node` instead of using protocols. This resulted in the compiler calling my `Identifier` initializer instead. I don't know what that proves. Frankly I'm at a loss. Help?

Comment: I'm unclear by your use of *compiler*. Are you saying that when your *running* app encounters a line like `let myClass = Description(start: 1, body: 1..<5, end: 5)` sometimes it tries to instantiate a `LyricBlock` instance? If so, could you provide your initialization code?

Comment: Yes to both. When I wrote __compiler__ I meant the Swift compiler. And the line where it gets instantiated is `let description = Description(start: charNumber, body: whitespace..<endWhitespace, end: endOfLineCharNumber)`. Nothing fancy being passed in, just integers. That instance is then attached to a parent node, but the `appendChild(_:)` function doesn't do any initialization or swapping out.

Comment: Ok. It sounds strange to me also. You mention `appendChild(_:)`. Could you include a few things in your question - the parent definition, the function where the instantiation and appending is happening? Maybe there's something happening there.

Comment: Edited to include `Node` and all instances of instantiation and appending.

Answer (score 0):

After some more tinkering I was able to at least partially solve this problem.

It turns out that, for whatever reason, ARC craps out on linked lists above a certain size. I was able to confirm this by creating a generic linked list in a new project and slowly stress testing it with progressively longer lists.

```
class LLNode<T> {

    var value: T?

    var next: LLNode<T>?

    weak var previous: LLNode<T>?

}

class LList<T> {

    var head: LLNode<T>

    var tail: LLNode<T>

    // boring old linked list implementation

}

let list = List<Int>()
for i in 0..<10000 {
    list.append(i)
}
```

Sure enough, after about 10,000 nodes I started getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS again on the generic list, but only when `list` was deinitialized. This matched the behavior I was getting exactly with the parser above. Since my code uses linked lists to model children in a tree (two dimensions of reference counting!), ARC was having to resolve all those references on its own -- and failing. Why it crashes like that is still beyond my ability to explain, but that at least explains the *source* of the crash.

To confirm, I created another linked list in C and just made a Swift wrapper around it, with all of the garbage collection being implemented in C.

```
import liblist

class List<T> {

    var list: UnsafeMutablePointer<llist>

    // Swift interface with list

    deinit {
        list_free(list)
    }
}
```

The wrapper was able to handle every size I threw at it -- as much as 500,000 nodes, at which point I felt satisfied and  stopped testing.

If anyone is interested in the full code I used to get around this problem, I've created a Swift package at https://github.com/dmcarth/List